make: *** No rule to make target 'src/basic.out', needed by 'build' error while using makefile extension on vs code
I'm trying to build a C project on vs code with a Makefile. I'm also using the 'Makefile Tools' extension by Microsoft to help with the build. Now, if I build the project manually using the 'make all' command via the terminal, it builds just fine and emits all the executables. But doing it in vs code with the extension results in failure.
.PHONY: all clean
.SUFFIXES: .c .exe .html .out

\_COLOR_BEGIN = \\033\[1;36m
\_COLOR_END = \\033\[m

PROJECT_NAME = ferox
PROJECT_FULL_NAME = c-krit/ferox

PROJECT_PREFIX = ${\_COLOR_BEGIN}${PROJECT_FULL_NAME}:${\_COLOR_END}

RAYLIB_INCLUDE_PATH ?= /usr/local/lib
RAYLIB_LIBRARY_PATH ?= /usr/local/include

INCLUDE_PATH = include
LIBRARY_PATH = ../lib
SOURCE_PATH = src

TARGETS ?= \
${SOURCE_PATH}/basic.out   \
${SOURCE_PATH}/cows.out    \
${SOURCE_PATH}/melon.out   \
${SOURCE_PATH}/query.out   \
${SOURCE_PATH}/raycast.out \
${SOURCE_PATH}/raylib.out

CC = cc
CFLAGS = -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -g -I${INCLUDE_PATH} -I../${INCLUDE_PATH} \
\-I${RAYLIB_INCLUDE_PATH} -O2 -std=gnu99
LDFLAGS = -L${LIBRARY_PATH} -L${RAYLIB_LIBRARY_PATH}
LDLIBS = -lferox -lraylib -ldl -lGL -lm -lpthread -lrt -lX11

all: pre-build build post-build

pre-build:
@printf "${PROJECT_PREFIX} Using: '${CC}' to build all examples.\\n"

build: ${TARGETS}

.c.exe .c.out:
@printf "${PROJECT_PREFIX} Compiling: $@ (from $\<)\\n"
@${CC} $\< -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}

.c.html:
@printf "${PROJECT_PREFIX} Compiling: $@ (from $\<)\\n"
@${CC} $\< -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS} ${WEBFLAGS}

post-build:
@printf "${PROJECT_PREFIX} Build complete.\\n"

clean:
@printf "${PROJECT_PREFIX} Cleaning up.\\n"
@rm -f ${SOURCE_PATH}/*.data ${SOURCE_PATH}/*.exe ${SOURCE_PATH}/*.js \
${SOURCE_PATH}/*.html ${SOURCE_PATH}/*.out ${SOURCE_PATH}/*.wasm

I've set the makefile path and build targets required by the extension.
Makefile path and build target set
After running the 'Build current target' option I get the following error
**c-krit/ferox: Using: 'cc' to build all examples.
make: *** No rule to make target 'src/basic.out', needed by 'build'.  Stop.

The terminal process "/usr/bin/bash '-c', ''make' 'all' '-f' '/home/abhishek/Desktop/ferox_examples/examples/Makefile''" failed to launch (exit code: 2).
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. **


There are missing TAB characters in the rules, but perhaps that is just the way you posted the code to the site. (Whatever you used to post it also added extra backslash escapes to the text.)

Please edit your question and format the errors correctly so that they're readable.  Also please double check the makefile you've pasted here as it seems to have a lot of stray backslashes in it that should not be there.  You say that this makefile works when you run it by hand so I have to assume that at least some of the backslashes are artifacts of your cut and paste and don't really exist in the makefile.
